# Get Wishlist Collection By Category

Tags: product, product-collection, magento-2.2.1

I am having difficulties with wishlist collections, i want them to be more like regular collections of filter like regular collections but this does not seem to be the case. Methods like **getSku** do not work and therefor my existing templates are not working very will with these collections.

I want to basically convert this (and some other collections) to get wishlist items by category:

```
public function _getProductCollectionCat($category)
{
    /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
    $collectioncat = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();

    $collectioncat = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices(
        $collectioncat
    )->setPageSize(
        $this->getProductsCount()
    )->setCurPage(
        1
    );

    $collectioncat->getSelect()->join('catalog_product_entity_tier_price as tier', 'price_index.entity_id = tier.entity_id');

    $collectioncat->addCategoryFilter($this->categoryRepository->get($category));

    $collectioncat->addFinalPrice()
          ->addMinimalPrice()
          ->getSelect()
          ->where('tier.all_groups = 0')
          ->where('tier.value < price_index.price');


    return $collectioncat;
}
```

This however filters by products with a group price i just want to filter by if the product is in the users wishlist. Can i just join a table and filter similarly to how tier prices were filtered above?

**Something Like Below:**

```
public function getWishlistProducts() {
    /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */

    $customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
    $wishlistId = $this->_wishlistRepository->create()->loadByCustomerId($customerId, true)->getId();


    $collectioncat = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();

    $collectioncat = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices(
        $collectioncat
    )->setPageSize(
        $this->getProductsCount()
    )->setCurPage(
        1
    );

    $collectioncat->getSelect()->join('wishlist_item as wishlist', 'price_index.entity_id = wishlist.product_id');

    $collectioncat->addCategoryFilter($this->categoryRepository->get($category));

    $collectioncat->addFinalPrice()
          ->addMinimalPrice()
          ->getSelect()
          ->where('wishlist.wishlist_id = ' . $wishlistId);


    return $collectioncat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this with the following:

```
public function __construct(
  ...
  \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory $wishlistRepository,
  \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
  ...
)
{
  ...
  $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
  $this->_wishlistRepository = $wishlistRepository;
  ...
}

public function getWishlistProductsCat($category) {
    /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */

    $customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
    $wishlistId = $this->_wishlistRepository->create()->loadByCustomerId($customerId, true)->getId();

    $collectioncat = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();

    $collectioncat = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices(
        $collectioncat
    )->setPageSize(
        $this->getProductsCount()
    )->setCurPage(
        1
    );

    $collectioncat->getSelect()->join('wishlist_item as wishlist', 'price_index.entity_id = wishlist.product_id');

    $collectioncat->addCategoryFilter($this->categoryRepository->get($category));

    $collectioncat->addFinalPrice()
          ->addMinimalPrice()
          ->getSelect()
          ->where('wishlist.wishlist_id = ' . $wishlistId);


    return $collectioncat;
}
```